# Form Validation with Dynamic Inputs

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

**Issue One**

A user can click a button to dynamically append inputs to a table.  Upon submission, each input should be validated. The following works for the first appended input, but not for subsequent inputs when all are empty (because the span already exists):

```
     $('input[id^=item_name]').each(function() {
        name = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[id^=item_name]').val();
        if(name==null || name==''){
            if ($('span:contains("Enter an item name")').length==0){
                $(this).closest('td').addClass('has-error');
                $(this).after('<span class="error" style="color:red;font-size:14px;">Enter an item name</span>');
            }
        }
    });
```

If I change `$('span:contains("Enter an item name")')` to `$(this).closest('span:contains("Enter an item name")').length==0`, it simply returns '0'. Where am I going wrong here?

**Issue Two**

The user should receive immediate feedback that a change to one of the dynamic inputs satisfied the error.

```
   $('input[id^=item_name]').focusout(function(){
        name = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[id^=item_name]').val();
        if(name==null || name==''){
            if ($('span:contains("Enter an item name")').length==0){
                $(this).closest('td').addClass('has-error');
                $(this).after('<span class="error" style="color:red;font-size:14px;">Enter an item name</span>');
            }
        }
        else {
            $('span:contains("Enter an item name")').remove();
        }   
    });
```

I may be having the same issue here with `$('span:contains("Enter an item name")')` . Your thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `$('span:contains("Enter an item name")')` to `$(this).closest('td').find('span:contains("Enter an item name")')` seems to work.